# Best way to select Random answer in a Form

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to select random answers in a form

```
  $('table').filter(function() { return ($(this).find('input').size() > 0); }).find('tr').each(function()
    {
        $(this).find('input').filter(function(){    return (Math.round(Math.random()) == 1);    }).each(function()
        {
            switch(this.type) {
                case 'checkbox':
                case 'radio':
                    this.checked = true;
                    this.trigger('click');
                        break;
                case 'password':
                case 'select-multiple':
                case 'select-one':
                case 'text':
                case 'textarea':
                    $(this).val('12345');
                        break;
            }
        });
    });
```

But it is sometimes not answering any input element in a row. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong with your code. The "type" attribute on the "input" tag can't be either "select-one", "select-multiple" or "textarea".

For textarea, it's a completely different tag: `<textarea>some text</textarea>`

For select it's also a different tag: `<select>` for single selects and `<select multiple="multiple">` for multiple selects.

You didn't specify "when" it doesn't work, but I believe that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply removing the first two lines as well as the last line of your code, as you could simply change $(this).find('input') with $('input') and have the exact same thing, just simpler. Also I would simply remove your randomization, as this is probably the reason that some of your rows are left without changes.
This might solve your problem:

```
$("input").each(function() {
        switch(this.type) {
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                this.checked = true;
                this.trigger('click');
                    break;
            case 'password':
            case 'select-multiple':
            case 'select-one':
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                $(this).val('12345');
                    break;
        }
});
```